# Risk of data on rewritable optical media being recovered after being erased

Tags: malware, burning, optical-media

When some software reads rewrited CD-RW or DVD-RW or BD-RW on the optical drive of one's notebook(or desktop) machine, is it possible that some malwares get the erased data in that CD-RW or DVD-RW or BD-RW?

Off course, this subject is related to whether we can erase the optical medium completely.

For example, in a burning software [Xfburn](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/xfburn) that I usually use
going down the menu:

- Actions
- Blank CD-RW
- Blank mode

Then there are two useful-looking blank mode options:

- "Full Blank (slow)"
- "Full Format"

Do these two blank mode options completely erase the old data on the optical medium?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into `xfburn` code, the `full blank` apparently erases the data and provide an empty disk but in `full format`, the data may still be retrieved.

Comment: I downloaded from http://archive.xfce.org/src/apps/xfburn/0.5/xfburn-0.5.0.tar.bz2 I'm trying to read the source code now. But I'm not familiar with C,so I don't know how much time it'll take...